How to track LWC clicks in event logs?
Can we capture LWC clicks in event logs ?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-logger/documentation

What is a "LWC click" anyway?!

@Felix van Hove A very fast click (think about it)

Capturing Lightning Web Component (LWC) clicks in event logs directly is not natively supported by Salesforce out of the box. However, you can achieve this by implementing a custom solution that tracks and logs LWC events.

Can you add a little more detail to this? It's been flagged as not an answer, and it doesn't really provide anything other than saying it's not built in.
